# HTML canvas Javascript mouse event, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

was wondering if it was possible to add/remove a circle on a canvas with a mouse event, such as mousedown. The main point being able to move a checker piece that is drawn on the canvas. Here my code that draws the pieces, I added the event listener, but i don't know how to draw another piece but clicking somewhere on the canvas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas=document.getElementById("checkerboard");
var context2d=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", moveP, false);
function play(){
    context2d.fillStyle="red";
    for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
        for(var y=0; y<3; y++){
            if(((x+y)%2)==1){
                context2d.beginPath();
                context2d.moveTo(x*80+5, y*80+40);
                context2d.arc(x*80+40, y*80+40, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                context2d.lineWidth=15;
                context2d.strokeStyle="#9F000F";
                context2d.stroke();
                context2d.fill();
            }
        }
    }
    context2d.fillStyle="grey";
    for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
        for(var y=5; y<8; y++){
            if(((x+y)%2)==1){
                context2d.beginPath();
                context2d.moveTo(x*80+5, y*80+40);
                context2d.arc(x*80+40, y*80+40, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                context2d.lineWidth=15;
                context2d.strokeStyle="#B6B6B4";
                context2d.stroke();
                context2d.fill();
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will be helpful.

Comment: it's doesn't work properly, because i mainly don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can listen for mousedown and mouseup events on the canvas like this:**

```
// get references to the canvas and its context

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// get the bounding box of the canvas
// (needed when calculating the mouse position)

var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX=BB.left;
var offsetY=BB.top;

// tell the browser to trigger handleMousedown & handleMouseup
// in response to mouse events

canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;
canvas.onmouseup=handleMouseup;
```

**And you can respond to mouse events like this:**

```
function handleMousedown(e){

    // tell the browser we're handling this event

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // calculate the mouse position

    var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
    var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;

    //now do your mouse down stuff
}

function handleMouseup(e){

    // tell the browser we're handling this event

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // calculate the mouse position

    var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
    var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;

    //now do your mouse up stuff
}
```

**Here's a Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tP3m4/